# Function creation using navicat throws error

Tags: mysql, navicat

I am creating an sql function using navicat which returns a value from the database,but it shows an error like below in the screenshot[image]

I was struggling for this full day on this problem.My sql function is as below

```
BEGIN

UPDATE counter  SET  key_value = (key_value  + 1)  WHERE key_name = 'param_key_name' ;
SELECT   key_value into c_count FROM counter WHERE key_name = 'param_key_name'  ;

RETURN  c_count;
END;
```

MY QUERIES are running successfully,but while it using inside the function this shows error like above.

My database is installed in another machine(but all queries are worked from my machine),any help will be highly appreciable.

Pls note `key_value and key_name` are my field name,my parameter is `'param_key_name'` which is varchar type,i am returning an integer value ie `c_count`

Answer (score 1):

; has a special meaning inside - for example - functions. Try changing the delimiter:

```
delimiter @
BEGIN

    UPDATE counter  SET  key_value = (key_value  + 1)  WHERE key_name = 'param_key_name' ;
    SELECT   key_value into c_count FROM counter WHERE key_name = 'param_key_name'  ;

    RETURN  c_count;
END @
```

Note that this is from the command line. Inside of Navicat you will probably have to change it in another way.